# VLFeat error in MATLAB R2010a - hists{ii} = getImageDescriptor(model, im);

Tags: matlab, sift, vlfeat

I am using the vl_sift tool of to extract features from a set of images for classification.
On running phow_caltech101(), the command prompt throws me an error as follows,

hists{ii} = getImageDescriptor(model, im);
??? Undefined function or method 'getImageDescriptor' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

I dont find the function 'getImageDescriptor' in any of repositories.
Can you please help me?

Best Regards,

Comment: Is it not just a subfunction defined within the main phow_caltech101 file? (If so I can't imagine why it doesn't work, though)

Answer (score 0):

It is there in the same file.[link](http://www.vlfeat.org/applications/caltech-101-code.html)

```
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
function hist = getImageDescriptor(model, im)
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------

im = standarizeImage(im) ;
width = size(im,2) ;
height = size(im,1) ;
numWords = size(model.vocab, 2) ;

% get PHOW features
[frames, descrs] = vl_phow(im, model.phowOpts{:}) ;

% quantize local descriptors into visual words
switch model.quantizer
  case 'vq'
    [drop, binsa] = min(vl_alldist(model.vocab, single(descrs)), [], 1) ;
  case 'kdtree'
    binsa = double(vl_kdtreequery(model.kdtree, model.vocab, ...
                                  single(descrs), ...
                                  'MaxComparisons', 50)) ;
end

for i = 1:length(model.numSpatialX)
  binsx = vl_binsearch(linspace(1,width,model.numSpatialX(i)+1), frames(1,:)) ;
  binsy = vl_binsearch(linspace(1,height,model.numSpatialY(i)+1), frames(2,:)) ;

  % combined quantization
  bins = sub2ind([model.numSpatialY(i), model.numSpatialX(i), numWords], ...
                 binsy,binsx,binsa) ;
  hist = zeros(model.numSpatialY(i) * model.numSpatialX(i) * numWords, 1) ;
  hist = vl_binsum(hist, ones(size(bins)), bins) ;
  hists{i} = single(hist / sum(hist)) ;
end
hist = cat(1,hists{:}) ;
hist = hist / sum(hist) ;
```